# "our site for contractors and serious DIYers."

Tags: discussion, bug

Not a question, but a reminder:

That's how the migration notice describes diy.stackexchange.com.

I believe all the moderators know this. But every so often someone still takes the diy name too literally and posts a comment which suggests professionals are not welcome.

I know SE is generally against renaming stacks to fix that kind of problem, so this may be unavoidable since most folks don't read meta. But I wanted this where I could easily point to it when correcting that mistake.

Comment: You're right, renaming a site is a Big Deal (and not only in the "would take a lot of dev time" sense) so we generally don't do it unless there's a significant problem or other reason to. As you say, a misguided comment "every so often" isn't enough. Good idea posting this for reference on meta, though! And if anyone comes across text on the site that describes this site in an incorrect (maybe obsolete) way, please post to meta about that too, and we'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone sees such a comment can they flag it. We'll remove it immediately we see the flag.